# Data insertion to Mysql Database from Excel

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, excel

I want to insert data from Excel to my Mysql Database. So far I've managed to insert just 1 column to the DB. I tried loops but cant seem to do it.

I'm new with ASP.NET C#. I can do this easily in PHP but I am having a hard time with ASP.NET.

Can anyone help me with inserting all the columns to the database table.

Here is my code:

```
 protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (importfile.HasFile)
    {
        string ex_userid = "";
        string ex_student_id = "";
        string ex_contact_name = "";
        string ex_contact_number = "";
        string ex_group_name = "";
        ex_group_name = groupname.Text;
        ex_userid = (String)(Session["id"]);
        string path = string.Concat((Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + importfile.FileName)));
        importfile.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
        OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

        oleConn.Open();
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand olecmd = new OleDbCommand("select*from [Sheet1$]", oleConn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapr = new OleDbDataAdapter(olecmd);
            adapr.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            OleDbDataReader oleReader = olecmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (oleReader.Read())
            {
                ex_student_id = oleReader[0].ToString();
                ex_contact_name = oleReader[1].ToString();
                ex_contact_number = oleReader[2].ToString();
            }
            string sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (user_id, student_id, contact_name, contact_number, group_name) VALUES (@a, @b, @c, @d, @e)";
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=bu-idesk;Uid=root;Pwd=;"))
            {
                con.Open();
                foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", ex_userid);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", r["Student_id"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", r["Student_name"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", r["Student_number"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", ex_group_name);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                oleConn.Close();
                con.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (MySqlException)
        { 

        } 
    }
}
```

My excel file: [image]

Comment: Did you debug your code and see what happens? What do you mean by _insert just 1 column_ exactly? You mean "just 1 row" instead? Or one row but just one column value, other columns are empty?

Comment: @SonerGönül Please see my excel file. The column of 2012-05338 was the only one that was inserted to my db. the others did not.

Comment: @mason Can you provide me with some source codes? Im a bit confused.

Comment: @mason I put up a breakpoint in the line "string sql = ...". I saw that only 1 column is read by the query.

Comment: You can try to use EPPlus library to read an excel file instead of the OleDbConnection , I think this will help you with the work of read the excel cells.

Comment: I didn't said that this will solve the problem, only I want to say that this library is simpler than other

Comment: @mason I think my real problem is it only reads 1 line in my excel file?

Comment: @mason I saw that when Im debbuging. How will I fixed that? Sorry. Newbie student

Comment: @mason Not exactly. I've changed cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", r["Userid"]); to cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", ex_userid); because its not a part of the table. Its from the Session["id"].